# How do I get subtasks using opt_fields using the Asana API?

Tags: json, api, rest, restful-url, asana

I'm able to get tons of information through a single query using the Asana RESTful API:

https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/10310306241538/tasks?opt_fields=notes,completed_at,projects,tags,tags.name&opt_pretty

But I can't seem to get subtasks using this query. Is it possible? I'm looking for subtask names, completion, and completion date, if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is not possible, but it's something we're looking to make possible in future. It's not directly on the roadmap yet so I can't give an estimate of when it'll be available I'm afraid. In the meantime you'll have to make an additional request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer – I guess I can always just run a `curl_multi` instead.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're brave enough for `curl_multi`! Granted, it's been over 5 years since I used it, so I'm gonna go out on a limb and hope that it's improved...

Comment: It'd be great if it's possible to learn number of subtasks for each task. Then  we could decide to make another request or not.

Comment: Note that where for some time there was a field for getting subtasks, this has now been deprecated; see https://forum.asana.com/t/the-subtasks-field-on-tasks-is-being-deprecated/44548